# C# - Function that mimics Constructor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm encountering an issue due to the way Unity constructs scripts / prefabs.

As we must instantiate our scripts via `Instantiate(Prefab)` I am unable to run the constructors of my scripts, which include overloading.

Example;

```
class A()
class B(string s1) : base()                   //Inherits from A
class C(string s1, string s2) : base(string)  //Inherits from B
```

Right now I have just changed the constructors to "Init" methods so;

```
void Init() {...}                  //Replaces class A constructor.
void Init(string s1){Init();...}   //Replaces class B constructor. This calls Init()
void Init(string s1, string s2){Init(s1);...}  //Replaces class C constructor. This calls Init(string)
```

Obviously this is not ideal, as if I want to initialise class C I run the risk of running the wrong Init function since I know of no way to overload / overwrite the function without having the same signature.

Is there a way to mimic the way constructors work for this? Any specific patterns I can employ to stop this from occurring as this design is obviously not ideal.

Comment: If I understand correctly (i.e. you want a class hierarchy with base A->B->C 'instantiated') then no, it's not possible. Prefabs are GameObject instances. As soon as you Instantiate, you create a GameObject, that's the base class. It will have Components, and one of these is a script. A single script. No class hierarchy as components are independent from each other. You need to find a healthy workaround that fits best your needs. Tell us what your plan/goal is with the hierarchy for a better/detailed answer

Comment: Honestly I just want to make sure the code is neat and usable by other programmers and to stop them from making mistakes with the code. The implementation itself works fine, the scripts inherit from one and have the same interface except for the init method, which is only an issue due to the lack of ability to use constructors. If there is no other way I'll leave it as it is and figure out a way to change it at some point down the line if I can.

Comment: Oh okay. The thing is. GameObject ("MonoBehaviour") is the "root of everything" in Unity. Whatever you do, it should be based around that. IF you want to make sure things go fine, you can use interfaces, or force different scripts to be added to particular prefabs (create them and init in Awake() -> script not added == error), add [RequireComponent(typeof(yourType))] and such.

Comment: Oh! One more thing! Is there anything that holds you back from abstraction? I mean. If "A" can be an abstract that can derive from MonoBehaviour, then "B" from "A", etc so you'll need to add "C" only as a component while you still have Update() etc and devs are forced to derive / do the right coding

Comment: @Mark Class B is actually already abstract, the issue is the parameters needed for classes that inherit from B - they differ in their constructors. I've refactored it a little now so make it less of an issue. None of them error with the wrong Init function but they won't function as expected.

Comment: Hm. Make them error then. But, this can also be a design flaw. Can you give an example why (for what) did you implement it this way? I assume you walked the "proper OOP way", not the "proper Unity way". I can be wrong tho on pretty much everything - in which case, Gunnar's solution is a good and kinda safe approach or forget overloading and add Init_PrefabName() or something instead (which will be hard to maintain if you rename stuff or add new prefabs, etc)

Comment: @Mark It's basically an extension of some aspects of the Unity UI. I've created a programattic way to let me link certain UI elements to variables (through delegates) as well as colour them for errors and show error warnings (with grouping). The implementation works perfectly, and if it wasn't Unity it would be a decent implementation as I follow all the OOP principles. There is no other way I can think of to have the UI items be constructed except via different parameters (since they are, of course, different). You've both given me useful insight though. So thanks to you both!

Comment: Say Mark ... **"GameObject ("MonoBehaviour") is the "root of everything" in Unity"**  You know, I'm not even sure you can say that!  If you say it is a "root" it implies you can build on it, or make variations or whatever.  Of course, you can't do that in any way at all.

Comment: Hi Questioning, you mention "as I follow all the OOP principles" - right, like I mention in my answer, **there may be some drastic misunderstanding** - heh!  Unity has no more connection to OO than the ocean has to the number 68.  It's an ECS system.  (sure, the current *language* used to write behaviors for components, is an OO language - but that's as important as asserting "I'm using a mouse! not a trackpad!" it's of no consequence.)

Comment: @JoeBlow Yes, I understand. I'm somewhat new to Unity so learning the way they want me to do things is one of the things I am working on. I fall back to what I understand, which is OO principles. I appreciate the response!

Answer (score 0):

If your class derives from `MonoBehaviour`, then some sort of init function can be used as you did or you can use `Awake/Start` if that fits. If your class doesn't derive from MonoBehaviour ("pure c# class") then you can use constructors.

Also, you can add a script with `AddComponent` if you just need to add a script to an existing object.

I don't quite understand your `Init` function structure though. Are those calling each other (from bottom to top)?

You can essentially make your init functions like constructors.

```
public void Init(){...}    // = empty constructor

public void Init(int a, int b){...}    // = constructor with two int parameters

public void Init(int c, string d){...}    // = constructor with an int and a string parameter
```

You can use comments so you get an infotext when using the function somewhere so you know which function does what. (Use `///` triple slash for function summary right above the function.)

**EDIT:**
Little example of how to call:

```
GameObject obj_A = (GameObject) Instantiate(prefab_A , ..., ...);
ClassA cls_A = obj_A.GetComponent<ClassA>();
cls_A.Init(5, "hello");

GameObject obj_B = (GameObject) Instantiate(prefab_B , ..., ...);
ClassB cls_B = obj_B.GetComponent<ClassB>();
cls_B.Init();

GameObject obj_C = (GameObject) Instantiate(prefab_C , ..., ...);
ClassC cls_C = obj_C.GetComponent<ClassC>();
cls_C.Init(1, "bye");
```

Comment: I've followed the same structure you've described - however each Init function fits each specific class. For example Init(string, string) would only work for class C and no other class. I am looking for a way to hide Init() and Init(string) if we are working with a class of type C so that the user / programmer doesn't accidentally call the wrong Init function. The same way you cannot call the constructor for class B if you are doing C = new C(string, string).

Comment: You can only call functions of a class when you do something like `classCRef.Init`. You will not be able to call a function of say class B this way.

Comment: I think we're misunderstanding one another. I can definitely call those functions because C inherits from B, so they share the same public functions. I will amend my post to say that, as I think I did miss that off.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, you could name them differently (ClassA_Init, ClassB_Init) and/or use the summary comment.

Comment: I think I will likely go for simply naming them differently (comments do explain the difference however that's likely not what users will see first).